# user input validation java classes

Tags: java, validation, class

This is my validation for user ID number, when testing, I entered an invalid string with a length less than 10 and it sets the input and doesn't execute the else statement.

## The Source Code:

```
private String phoneNum;

public personalInfo(String phNum) {
    setPhoneNum(phNum);
}

public String getPhoneNum() {
    return phoneNum;
}

public void setPhoneNum(String phNum) {
    if (phoneNum.startsWith("05")&&(phoneNum.length()==10)){
        phoneNum = phNum;
    }
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Invalid Phone Number!");
}
```

Comment: How are you calling this code? Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

your method looks like this...

```
public void setPhoneNum(String phNum) {
    if (phoneNum.startsWith("05")&&(phoneNum.length()==10)){
        phoneNum = phNum;
    }
```

and there you are not validating the parameter, but the variable `phoneNum`...

do instead:

```
public void setPhoneNum(String phNum) {
    if (phNum.startsWith("05")&&(phNum.length()==10)){
        phoneNum = phNum;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be validating the value you that you are getting (`phNum`) and set it to the member variable `phoneNum`.

```
if (phNum.startsWith("05")&&(phNum.length()==10)){
    phoneNum = phNum;
}
```